# How to understand that a layout completed drawing?

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When has the Activity finished drawing itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171216/when-has-the-activity-finished-drawing-itself)

I want to understand that when layout finishes drawing itself and all its children, is there way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your view ( the root node ) a custom view - you can then override onDraw - when the end of which is reached all views should be drawn