# How to understand that android finished drawing a view?

Tags: android, android-view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When has the Activity finished drawing itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171216/when-has-the-activity-finished-drawing-itself)

I want to know when a view completes its drawing, is that possible? How can I understand if android finished drawing a view or not?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a ViewTreeObserver to it.

Sample,

```
      TextView pagerView1=new TextView(this);
   ViewTreeObserver textViewTreeObserver=pagerView1.getViewTreeObserver();
        textViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                           //Do your operations here. 

                    pagerView1.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);



            }
        });
```

This is a Listener which gets called once that particular gets drawn completely. So I have made it use for TextView. Similarly you can make use of any view you do. And inside onGlobalLayout() you can do your code.

Comment: to remove listener View.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(victim) can be better idea...because in your case it callback loop is not complete and u trying to remove it.

Comment: i set using same listener for scroll view, in this case it's keep on calling while scrolling, have any idea about to get state when scrolling finished.

Comment: Where did the "obs" variable come from?

Comment: obs is the variable of the view to which you are setting the layoutlistener. Sorry! I didn't mention it.