# How do I receive a callback when drawing graph completes in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, multithreading, mpandroidchart

I am having an issue where I am refreshing a LineDataSet graph real time by updating the data and calling mMyChart.invalidate().

One thread is requesting the data from a server, processing it, and sending it via a message to the second thread, which is the main activity thread and is responsible for drawing the graph.

The issue is this call to invalidate seems to complete before the chart has actually redrawn, so my other thread requesting the data goes off and requests more data and sends it to the thread to re draw the chart.  The thread drawing the charts gets very behind after a while and starts taking a long time to respond to anything, the longer it has been running, the longer it takes.

My question is straight forward in that I want to make it so I don't continue requesting data until the plot has finished drawing.  How do I receive a callback when drawing completes?  Alternately, is there a way to detect when it is drawing?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 2):

You could try a [`ViewTreeObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) (related SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477026/how-to-understand-that-android-finished-drawing-a-view))

> A view tree observer is used to register listeners that can be notified of global changes in the view tree. Such global events include, but are not limited to, layout of the whole tree, beginning of the drawing pass, touch mode change.... A `ViewTreeObserver` should never be instantiated by applications as it is provided by the views hierarchy. Refer to [`getViewTreeObserver()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getViewTreeObserver()) for more information.

Or you could try extending the particular `Chart` type you are using and override `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` to call a listener when the draw pass completes:

```
public class ExtendedBarChart extends BarChart {
    public ExtendedBarChart(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExtendedBarChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExtendedBarChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // TODO: Drawing completed, execute callback...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try.